# How can i draw multiple shapes on d3 javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Hi i want to demonstrate my dots on a map by 2 shapes: `circle` and `rectangle`. i use filter to separate my data into 2 parts: `equal to 1` or `equal to 0`. But i just can demonstrate circles.

I just can demonstrate 1 rectangle althought my data has many rows that satify the condition. I see that the coordinate for rectangle is in my data's last row. Maybe the filter make the file's pointer go to last place? What wrong? Can you guys point out my problem?

**My code**

```
// draw  circle dots
  svg.selectAll(".dot")
      .data(data).enter()
      .append("circle")
       .filter(function(d) { return d.class ==0})
      .attr("class", "dot")
      .attr("r", 3.5)
      .attr("cx", xMap)

      .attr("cy", yMap)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(cValue(d));})
      .on("mouseover", function(d) {
          tooltip.transition()
               .duration(200)
               .style("opacity", .9);
          tooltip.html(d.class1 + "<br/> (" + xValue(d)
            + ", " + yValue(d) + ")")
               .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 5) + "px")
               .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
      })
      .on("mouseout", function(d) {
          tooltip.transition()
               .duration(500)
               .style("opacity", 0);
      });
//Draw rectangle dot

svg.selectAll(".rec")
    .data(data).enter().append("rect")
     .filter(function(d) { return d.class ==1})
    .attr("class", "rec")
    .attr("cx", xMap)
    .attr("cy", yMap)
    .attr("height", 30)
    .attr("width", 30)
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(cValue(d));})
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
        tooltip.transition()
             .duration(200)
             .style("opacity", .9);
        tooltip.html(d.class1 + "<br/> (" + xValue(d)
        + ", " + yValue(d) + ")")
             .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 5) + "px")
             .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {
        tooltip.transition()
             .duration(500)
             .style("opacity", 0);
    });
```

my data.csv

```
tree    house   class   class1

    0.12804 0.25792 0   B
    0.14595 0.33472 0   B
    0.23117 0.48474 0   C
    0.088995    0.25033 0   B
    0.12231 0.40285 0   C
    0.14204 0.28154 0   B
    1.0284  0.02235 0   A
    0.023085    0.38046 0   B
    0.074772    0.43056 0   C
    -0.046482   0.19074 0   B
    0.10548 0.11783 0   B
    0.21276 0.20738 0   B
    -0.064076   0.089246    0   A
    -0.029258   0.48967 0   C
    0.1851  0.20177 0   B
    0.029084    0.11508 1   B
    0.10206 0.27658     1    B
    0.11558 0.20622    1     B
    0.15363 0.29544    1       B
    -0.40068    0.94515 1   E
    0.057977    0.26218 1   B
    0.089279    0.39531 1   B
```

[image]

Comment: Pleas crop your image because of the massive amount of unneccessary whitespace.

Comment: @rollstuhlfahrer thank you ,i approved your edit. I am new at posting question. Do you know my problem sir?